# Linear transformation: vectors landing at unintended places, manim

Tags: python, manim

when applying a Linear transformation with a matrix [3, 0],[0, 2], the i hat should elongate to 3 times its length and j hat should elongate to 2 times its length, right? The i hat shouldn't move in the direction of j hat because the second coordinate is zero.
But when I rendered the animation, what I got is this:[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eimkL.png)

Look, instead of the i hat (green) moving from (2,-1) to (6,-3) it has moved a little in the direction of j hat?

Why is this so? Can somebody explain to me?

Comment: @j1-lee But have you seen [this](https://youtu.be/P2LTAUO1TdA?t=377)

Comment: @j1-lee I got it. It was not a problem with my Linear Algebra  but with manim. Actually, When we apply A=[[2 ,-1],[-1 , 3]]and then B= [[3 , 0],[0 , 2]], we expect to see the resultant matrix BA= [[6 , -2],[-3 , 6]]. But manim actually shows AB .

Comment: @j1-lee But  as A and B are both matrices here, the  composite matrix is BA. Its like functions f(g(x)) : f(x) applied after g(x). The order is g(x) then f(x). The same is for matrices

Comment: @j1-lee Thanks, I am making a video explaining adjoints as linear transformations.

Comment: @j1-lee The A=[[2 ,-1],[-1 , 3]] is to move i hat to (2,-1) and j hat to (-1,3). So, In a way, I am moving the entire vector space and not just a single vector. So, every vector in this vector space will be transformed. Have you watched [this video](https://youtu.be/XkY2DOUCWMU)? It visualizes all these transformations.

Answer (score 0):

When we "apply" matrix in manim with `self.apply_matrix` , it is not actually applying the matrix.

For example, if we `self.apply_matrix(A)` and then `self.apply_matrix(B)`, what we should get is the matrix BA which is the result of applying B after A.

But what we actually get is AB.

And as matrix multiplication is not commutative, these are different. That is why we get the wrong transformation.

Don't know why manim is behaving this way.